# Application input and output audio through two separate devices?

Tags: audio, audio-output

I am running windows 8.1 64 bit, and have a soundblaster zxr sound card (this may or may not be relevant in some way). I am also using an M-Audio Fast Track USB audio interface, which has its own version of an ASIO driver. I can currently use my audio interface to take input from my electric guitar, run it through some amp simulation/recording software, and then have the output come back out through one of the audio interface's outputs. The problem is that it forces me to use that device as both input and output.

I want to be able to take the input from that device, run it through the software, and output to a different device through my sound card, all while maintaining as low latency as possible, to allow me to listen to the modified sound in real time, as if it were coming out of a real guitar amp.

I have looked at some software such as VB-Virtual Audio Cable, but it seems like this is only able to route audio from one application to another, which is not what I am going for.

EDIT: I use several sound processing applications, all of which seem to have the same issue. The ones I use mainly are Adobe Audition, and IK Multimedia's Amplitube 3.

Comment: This sounds like it should be a feature of the audio processing software you're using.  Without knowing what it is, we probably won't be able to help much.